# Is credit score an international thing?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score

I have moved from the Netherlands to the United Kingdom and credit score is a big thing here, while afaik there is no such thing in the Netherlands.

Will a positive or negative credit score in the UK impact a future credit score if I would move, e.g. to the US?

Comment: There is something like that in the Netherlands, through the Bureau Kredietregistratie (BKR). It's not exactly the same, but the main idea is very similar I would say, although I don't think they look at things like credit utilization.

Answer (score 11):

For most parts, each country has its own system of credit risk assessment. In the EU they *may* be able to share some information (although I doubt it), but I have not heard of any way for the US credit scoring companies (which are private entities) to get any info from foreign countries. In the US the credit scoring is tied to your US SSN, which you never use in any other country, even if you have it, without a direct relation to a US financial or tax issue.